# C# with MySQL Add Data to Binding Source stop at record #8

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding, datagridview

I always failed to load DataGridView customers. They always freeze on record #8

I have a Customers class under my apps namespace like this

```
public class Customers
    {
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NoSPU { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Telp { get; set; }
        public string Kavling { get; set; }
        public string Tipe { get; set; }
        public string Pokok { get; set; }
        public string Bunga { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my code to add item to customersBindingSource in my DataGridView and I put in formLoad event

```
string query = "select * from customer";           
            customersBindingSource.Clear();
            Int32 i = 0;
            MySqlDataReader reader = dx.findQuery(query);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                i++;
                customersBindingSource.Add(new Customers() {
                    No = i.ToString(),
                    ID = reader.GetString("id"),
                    NoSPU = reader.GetString("nospu"),
                    Name = reader.GetString("nama"),
                    Telp = reader.GetString("telp"),
                    Kavling = reader.GetString("kavling"),
                    Tipe = reader.GetString("tipe") 
                });
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()+" OKE");
            }
            reader.Close();
```

If I'm trying with data less than 8 on customers table it always work, but when I add new customers more than 8 it's always freeze, customers forms doesn't show up. Are there's a limitation or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this way:

> ```
> // Create and populate the list of DemoCustomer objects
> // which will supply data to the DataGridView.
> List<DemoCustomer> customerList = new List<DemoCustomer>();
> customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());
> customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());
> customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());
>
> // Bind the list to the BindingSource.
> this.customersBindingSource.DataSource = customerList;
> ```

hope it can help you.